# categorize image and video files as albums

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to categorize image and video files as albums .My application is developed in asp.net and sql2005.Now i am uploading the image s and videos .My aim is to the user can create an album and he should upload files to that album .There have any way to do this?I am using to show the files that uploaded in repeater as links that are populated from database.How can i categorize this and how to show as albums(or folders)
There have any way please help me...

Comment: This is a very wide question - can you narrow it a little ?

Comment: My aim is to the user can create an album and he should upload files to that album .There have any way to do this?I am using to show the files that uploaded in repeater as links that are populated from database.

Answer (score 1):

You should design your database to store information you want - viz. type of the media (photo/video), album names, etc.

You should then use asp.net (or any other suitable framework/language) to retreive the relevant information from the tables and display them to the user.

Here is a first-cut database schema to get you started.

```
Media_Table 
id user_id album_id media_name media_type

User_Table (stores user information)
id user_id

Album_Table (stores album information)
id album_id user_id album_name
```

Given an album id you can retrieve all the files under it using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Media_Table WHERE album_id = <what-ever album you want>
```

ps: This is a database related question so please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, but please invest some time in reading about databases.  This seems like a "homework" kind of problem.